# Xamarin forms app shell background color bottom tabs in xaml

Tags: forms, shell, xaml, xamarin, tabs

I am trying to change the background color of the tabs on the bottom, but this does not work:
I use the latest version of xamarin forms and made a shell app.
In appshell xaml I changed the background color to a different color but when I start the app, nothing is changed.
I hope somebody can explain me what how to change the background color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a look at this official document [Xamarin.Forms Shell Page Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/configuration).You can [Styling Xamarin.Forms Apps using XAML Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/index).

For example , if want to change Tab Bar backgroud color, you can set a stlye as follow:

```
<Shell.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="BearsShell" 
     TargetType="Element" 
     BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
     <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor"
         Value="#546DFE"/>
  </Style>
</Shell.Resources>
```

Then you can set style in Shell Content:

```
<ShellContent Route="bears"
            Style="{StaticResource BearsShell}"
            Title="Bears"
            Icon="bear.png"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:BearsPage}" />
```

[image]

Note: In official document , there is a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-xaminals/) for reference.